# What does the "Charging is not supported with this device" error mean?

Tags: ipod-touch, charging

Sometimes when I plug my iPod touch into a dock or cable I get the message `Charging is not supported with this device`.  What's that mean?  Did Apple change the pin configuration of the dock connector?

Comment: Is it always the same with one dock or cable? I mean if you dock your iPod into your "dock A" do you receive that message each time? Or does it work sometimes and sometimes it does not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the charger one designed for an older iPod with charging on the firewire pins in the dock connector. The spec has changed in more recent devices to only charge from the usb power pins so it is detecting the older configuration and giving you this message

Comment: So how do you fix the problem then?

Comment: [Adapt the connector](http://www.scosche.com/consumer-tech/product/1695)

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your charger does not match your device/iPod.